# Multiple CAML query to filter Data list view

Tags: caml-query

My Custom list has four columns(Doc ID, Created by, Assigned To, Assigned date). I want to filter the data in Data list view.

In my page, there are 4 text boxes and a Button is there for the user input (Doc ID, Created by, Assigned To, Assigned date )

When the user enters his input in text boxes and clicks the save button how do i change the filter query at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XmlDefinition property of the XsltListViewWebPart. [Here](http://spboom.com/sharepoint-development/sharepoint-2010-filtering-xsltlistviewwebpart-using-caml-query/) you can find good example how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can generate CAML query on page dynamically and then send in to List view as string parameter (in query string, or in hidden form field):

```
             <View>
                <Query>
                    {CAMLQueryString}
                </Query>
                <ViewFields>
                 ...
                </ViewFields>
                <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
                <Aggregations Value="Off"/>
                <Toolbar Type="Standard"/>
            </View>
```